# Adding a pages/main controller for 'brochure-site' section of a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controllers

I am developing a rails application that will eventually contain products, users, and orders. For now I am just trying to get their 'brochure site' up. Rather than build it twice I thought to simply start with the rails application making it easily to rapidly move on as they need. That said...I am looking for advice on the best way to build out the simple pages like, Home, About Us, etc.

I know that I can accomplish this by simply adding those pages in the public directory but know there is a better way to accomplish this. I have tried using [this](http://www.buildingwebapps.com/podcasts/79334-the-simplest-possible-rails-application/24793-show-notes) Tutorial to create a pages controller but simply generating a controller with the corresponding views doesn't seem to work as it does in the tutorial (perhaps it is an older tut).

What are the best practices here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#hello-rails)?

Comment: That's what I needed. Just couldn't figure out the best way to do it. Thanks. I will mark this as the answer in '9 minutes'.